# In a form I have two fields. One OR the other is required. Can I do this with VF/Apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, form, apexinputfield

I know I could completed this on the front end or with some JS, but I am already using the required attribute on the apex:inputField for all the other fields, so it would be nice if I could make this consistent. Here are the two fields:

```
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>{!$ObjectType.Asset.fields.SerialNumber.label}<span class="required-ast">SN or Order Number is required</span></label>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!asset.SerialNumber}" required="true"/>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>{!$ObjectType.Asset.fields.Order_Number__c.label}<span class="required-ast">SN or Order Number is required</span></label>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!asset.Order_Number__c}" required="true"/>
                </div>
```

and here is the submit button, if relevant:

```
                <div class="input-group">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit"/>
                </div>
```

Comment: add a check in your `save()` method to see if any of them is filled in?

Comment: @Novarg. The downside to that being that he will then need to use pagemessages to tell the user they need to complete one or the other of the fields. jQuery validation would be a cleaner solution and would show that one or the other of the two fields is required.

Comment: So, I think I will need to run an onclick on the commandButton, but is there a way to pass in the click event into the js function?

Comment: @Novarg any thoughts?

Comment: @notthehoff, you can easily pass along the click event like this  
`<apex:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="yourJSFunction(event)" />`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add a validation rule?

Criteria can be like:

```
AND(
ISBLANK(Pickup_Street__c),
ISBLANK(Pickup_CIty__c)
)
```

Comment: It is coming in from a vf page form. So, no matter the validation on the field from within sf, my understanding is that it does not impact validation on the front end.

Comment: Nope, If you add validation rule on your object it will validate your data no matter from where its coming from i.e. page , api import anything ....

Comment: So, how would the person who is filling out the form know that they have entered bad data?

Comment: I will call them and tell them about wrong data  :D.... sorry i was just tryinf to be funny ... try validation rule you will get it .. just 5mins job